# Why does this for loop give me this error?

Tags: python-3.x, nameerror

I wrote the following loop:

```
pdFrame = []
for dir, subdir, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if glob2.fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.gz'):
            columns = ['Gene_ID', file[:file.find('.')]]
            df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dir, file), compression='gzip', sep='\t', names=columns, header=None)
            df = df.set_index('Gene_ID')
            for name, value in df.items():
                pdFrame.append(value)
            data_frame = pd.concat(pdFrame, axis=1, ignore_index=False)
data_frame.to_csv('final_samples.csv', header=True)
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

"NameError: name 'data_frame' is not defined"

Based on the error, there is some value that must be 'False' , which is why the values aren't posting to the variable, but I don't understand why.

Comment: You should tag this with a language..

Comment: Please share more details, along with your debugging attempts

Answer (score 0):

You should try declaring `data_frame` outside of the conditional statement. In a scenario where your `if` statement doesn't return true, `data_frame` never gets defined. As a result of that `data_frame.to_csv()` cannot be called, because it doesn't exist.

Alternatively you can check if `data_frame` is not null before calling to_csv()

```
pdFrame = []
data_frame = None
for dir, subdir, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if glob2.fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.gz'):
            columns = ['Gene_ID', file[:file.find('.')]]
            df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dir, file), compression='gzip', sep='\t', names=columns, header=None)
            df = df.set_index('Gene_ID')
            for name, value in df.items():
                pdFrame.append(value)
            data_frame = pd.concat(pdFrame, axis=1, ignore_index=False)
if data_frame is not None:
    data_frame.to_csv('final_samples.csv', header=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your solution, but the loop is still not working. It seems to create a variable with 'none' as its string. For some reason, it still is not recognizing data_frame as a variable that will hold my values. Is there anything else that I can try?